# Referral incentive

Tags: php, mysql

I am quite new to php and mysql. I have added a registration field "Referral" to my index. I added it the easiest way i came up with was to just add ref row in player table. When the user inputs a referral during the registration it gets stored to the database without checking if username inputed by the new user is valid or not.

```html
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $ref      = $_POST['ref'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT username FROM `players` WHERE username='$username'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        echo '<br /><div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' . lang_key("username_taken") . '</div>';
    } else {
        $sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT email FROM `players` WHERE email='$email'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql2) > 0) {
            echo '<br /><div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>  ' . lang_key("email_taken") . '</div>';
        } else {
            $money    = $row['startmoney'];
            $gold     = $row['startgold'];
            $themeid  = $rowtd['id'];
            $langcode = $rowld['langcode'];
            
            $insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `players` (username, password, email, ref, money, gold, theme, language) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$ref', '$money', '$gold', '$themeid', '$langcode')");
```

Today i'm looking to give incentives upon referring people. So I have been breaking down the ways I got to do this. I came up with something like this.

```
 $sql3 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ref FROM `players` WHERE ref='$ref'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql3) > 0) {
        echo $player_update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `players` SET money=money+'5000' WHERE ref='$ref'");';
   }else{
```

This does not work and i'm unsure if this is how I should be doing in the first place.. I'm a beginner and learned all myself so tip would be highly appreciated, thank you to anyone reading/helping!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Sorry about all the warnings here, but this code is chock full of red flags and if this is a public site it could be cracked wide open in seconds. Since this appears to involve some kind of currency, virtual or otherwise, you're going to be a target and you must pay attention to security concerns.

Comment: You don't have to echo your query, the php `mysqli_query();` will already fire by itself. So change `echo $player_update = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE players SET money=money+'5000' WHERE ref='$ref'");';` to `mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE players SET money=money+'5000' WHERE ref='$ref'");`. However, do not ignore the warnings from the past comments. If it still doesn't work, put the sql into a php variable, and `var_dump($sql)`, or simply do `echo $sql;` and copy paste it into your workbench manually and see if you get any errors.

Comment: You should be using a framework to build your application, it will give you a solid foundation to build on. [Laravel](http://laravel.com) as one example has a lot of community supplied documentation [en Français](https://laravel.sillo.org/laravel-5/). As a more general guide, look at [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com).

Comment: thanks will look into lavarel for sure!